# C# windows forms application:How can I replace a single line in a textfile without deleting the original file?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, streamwriter

I am making a project that uses streamreader and streamwriter, Is it possible that I only replace or save a text in an specific line only without affecting the other lines? 
if I make like this

```
streamreader sr = new streamreader(@"txtfile");
list<string> lines = new list<string>();
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
sr.readline();
{
     lines.Add(sr.ReadLine();
}

//put in textbox
sr.close();

{
streamwriter sw = new streamwriter(@"txtfile");
sw.WriteLine(textBox1.text);
sw.close();
}
```

this is just a sample, but Is it possible that I use list also un streamwriter?

Comment: explain more about what are you trying to do

Comment: read the file (all content). modify as you like, then write (rewrite and replace) the modified text into the same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just change a line as such but you can to **ReadAllLines**, **find the line you want to change**, **change it and write all of it to the file again** :

```
StringBuilder newFile = new StringBuilder();
string temp = "";
string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(@"txtfile");

foreach (string line in file)
{
    if (line.Contains("string you want to replace"))
    {
        temp = line.Replace("string you want to replace", "New String");
        newFile.Append(temp + "\r\n");
        continue;
    }
    newFile.Append(line + "\r\n");
}

File.WriteAllText(@"txtfile", newFile.ToString());
```

Comment: ahhh, Is it possible to use list in writeline like in the streamreader that only write in a specific line thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a one line solution (code golf :) ) you can use

```
string path = @"C:\Test.txt";
string lineToReplace = "Relpace This Line";
string newLineValue = "I Replaced This Line";

File.WriteAllLines(path, File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(line => line.Equals(lineToReplace) ? newLineValue : line));
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the file into memory, changing the line(s) you want to change, close the reader, open the file for writing, write the new contents of the file out.